# Ctrl-Fで検索時にエラーが発生する: 数値/IPアドレス範囲の不正なフォーマットが検出されました

Tags: emeditor

EmEditor ver 20.0.4 で、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>F</kbd> で検索文字列を入れて次を検索ボタンを押すと、以下のメッセージが出て検索ができません。

> 数値/IPアドレス範囲の不正なフォーマットが検出されました。

そのあと検索ダイアログを閉じて <kbd>F3</kbd> を押すと検索されます。
回避方法はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

念のため確認ですが、[検索] ダイアログで、[数値範囲] オプションがチェックされていないでしょうか? [(無し)] が選択されているでしょうか?

Comment: すみません。そこの設定でした！「数値範囲」がチェックされていました。ありがとうございました